# Right way to convert indexed array to arrays of strings in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

Which is the most correct and less resource-intensive way when converting an indexed array to an array of strings in PHP.
Example:

```
[ 0 => 'Zero', 1 => 'One', 2 => 'Two', 3 => 'Three' ];
```

Into:

```
[ 'Zero', 'One', 'Two', 'Three' ];
```

Comment: Those are exactly the same in PHP. If keys are different (non-consecutive or not starting with 0 or not integers), [`array_values`](https://www.php.net/array_values) would be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 2):

In PHP, there are three types of arrays:

- Indexed arrays: Arrays with a numeric index
- Associative arrays: Arrays with named keys
- Multidimensional arrays: Arrays containing one or more arrays

if you create an array like that `$arr = [ 'Zero', 'One', 'Two', 'Three' ];` it is by default indexed `Array ( [0] => Zero [1] => One [2] => Two [3] => Three )`

What you want to achieve, it is implemented by default in php, you can benefit from the function `array_values` only if the keys of an array in different order.

```php
$arr = [ 'Zero', 'One', 'Two', 'Three' ];
print_r($arr);//Array ( [0] => Zero [1] => One [2] => Two [3] => Three )
```

in this case is the same thing

```php
$arr = [ 0 => 'Zero', 1 => 'One', 2 => 'Two', 3 => 'Three' ];
print_r(array_values($arr));//Array ( [0] => Zero [1] => One [2] => Two [3] => Three )
```